# About vector bundle-valued differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, inner-products, differential-forms, vector-bundles

In my course I saw this question and I would like if it is posible. Let  $$\pi:E\longrightarrow M$$ a finite dimensional complex vector bundle over a semi-Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, with a hermitian structure $h$ and a compatible linear connection $$\nabla:\Gamma(M,E)\longrightarrow \Omega(M)\otimes_{C^\infty(M)}\Gamma(M,E)$$ (where $C^\infty(M)$ is the space of real-valued smooth functions). The question is if it is posible to define products $$\Omega(M,E)\times \Omega(M,E)\longrightarrow  C^\infty(M)$$ $$\Omega(M,E)\times \Omega(M,E)\longrightarrow  \mathbb{R} $$ where $\Omega(M,E)$ is the space of all $E$-valued differential forms on $M$. I suppose that the last one has to be a kind of inner product, but I am not so sure.

Comment: You can use the hermitian inner product to pair the sections pointwise and get a *complex* number (not real number), and then integrate over $M$ to get a *complex number* if 
$M$ is compact.

Comment: you mean, like using a local frame??

Comment: Locally, you can write your bundle-valued forms as linear combinations $\omega=\sum \omega_i\otimes s_i$ and $\eta = \sum \eta_i\otimes t_i$, and then take $[\omega\wedge\eta] = \sum h(s_i,t_i)(\omega_i\wedge\eta_i)$. You could do this without a hermitian structure if you pair $E$ and $E^*$.